# Understanding postgres reason for picking this query plan

Tags: postgresql, explain

I ran a query:

```
select * from orderline where orderid = 12345 and status > 0
```

that gave me the following plan:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on orderline  (cost=286370.00..531410.78 rows=76372 width=155)
  Recheck Cond: ((orderid = 12081976) AND (itemstatus > 0))
  ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=286370.00..286370.00 rows=76372 width=0)
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on orderline_orderid_index  (cost=0.00..4239.65 rows=229117 width=0)
              Index Cond: (orderid = 12081976)
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on orderline_status  (cost=0.00..282091.91 rows=15274484 width=0)
              Index Cond: (status > 0)
```

I wanted to understand why postgres decided to run two separate index scans rather than the filter on the forign key (`orderline_orderid` - which returns about 5 rows out of millions) then filtering `status` from these results.

How can I work out what I've set up wrong here? (I'm assuming index fragmentation or maybe status shouldn't have an index?)

**EDIT:** I tried some of the things in the comments and the discovered the following:

I thought the cause of the issue was the index as I removed it and the problem went away:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on orderline  (cost=4258.75..597209.93 rows=76372 width=155)
  Recheck Cond: (orderid = 12081976)
  Filter: (status > 0)
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on orderline_orderid_index  (cost=0.00..4239.65 rows=229117 width=0)
        Index Cond: (orderid = 12081976)
```

However, I removed and added then index and then ran analyse and the the follow occured:

```
Index Scan using orderline_orderid_index on orderline  (cost=0.00..14.87 rows=4 width=63)
  Index Cond: (orderid = 12085242)
  Filter: (status > 0)
```

So is this because I rebuilt the index, or because I ran analyse?

Comment: Do you have a very large number of rows and a very low number of different status values?

Comment: Yes @DaveHowes, and how do I migrate?

Comment: I don;t know much about Postgres, but I have used Ingres in the past. It certainly didn't like indexes that had a small range of values - I'd try dropping that index and seeing what that does to the query plan

Comment: You can click on `close`, chose `off topic` and you should be able to choose the dba site to migrate it to. [See here for more on closing questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250)

Comment: thanks @GarethD I did this - I think it needs a 5th vote to move?

Comment: You think that 5 rows should match orderid = 12345 but PostgreSQL thinks there will be 229117.  Has your table been analyzed recently?

Comment: @jjanes yes 5 rows... I don't know, so I analysed and ran it again. Same result.

Comment: What is default_statistics_target?  What is the output of "select * from pg_stats where tablename ='orderline' and attname='orderid' \x\g\x" ?

Comment: @jjanes unsure - there is no default_statistics_target in that query.. the output is
public;orderline;status;f;0;2;4;{0,1,2,-1};{0.547392,0.23746,0.213117,0.00203083};<NULL>;0.434958

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Postgres had no idea how your values are distributed. It guessed that there's 229117 rows with `orderid = 12081976` when it really was 5 of them. It has then chosen a plan which was optimal for 229117 rows.

When you ran `analyze` it was able to generate and save statistics about distribution of values in your table. And then it knew that there's about 4 rows with this orderid. And this allowed it to pick a better plan.

So it is `analyze` that caused this. Remember to run it after large changes to database data — for example after importing from external source.

Also — when you analyze your plans try to use `explain analyze [query];` instead of just `explain [query];`. You can paste it to [explain.depesz.com](http://explain.depesz.com/) for easier to understand format.

Comment: I assumed `vhcid` in first plan is really `orderid` and `itemstatus`=`status`. It did not made sense to me otherwise.

Comment: yes, I changed it so the context would be more understandable... caught red handed :)

Comment: this was on a restored db, so maybe that is what the stats didn't seem to exist.